# Can't get the autocomplete search form to work

Tags: autocomplete, search-form

I'm implementing a search form that displays suggestions as you start typing but can't get it to work..the problem is that when you start typing it doesn't shows any suggestion. Can you help me to get the code right? Many thanks!

This is the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="autocomplete" type="text"></div>




<script>
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: [ 
{ id : "Google", value : "Google"},
{ id : "Yahoo", value : "Yahoo"},
],
minLength: 1,
open: function(event, ui) { 
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").unbind("click");
var data = $(this).data("autocomplete");
console.log(data);
for(var i=0; i<=data.options.source.length-1;i++)
{
                                    var s = data.options.source[i];
                                    $("li.ui-menu-item a:contains(" + s.value + ")").attr("href", "/" + s.id);
                                  }

                                } 

    });

    /*
    $("input#autocomplete").bind("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) { 
        //alert(ui.item.id + ' - ' +  ui.item.value); 
        //document.location.href = ui.item.id + '/' + ui.item.value;
        //event.preventDefault; 
        } );
    */
    </script>
```

Comment: no need to answer anymore..found out the problem..i forgot to add <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the code:

```
<div id="search">
  <input list="results" id="project" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { checkInput(this.value); return false; }" />
</div>
```

The avaible results...

```
<datalist id="results">
  <option>Demo</option>    
  <option>Example</option>
  <option>pizza</option>
</datalist>
```

Finally the javascript

```
function checkInput(searchQuery)
{
if(searchQuery=="Home")
{
    window.location = "Home.html";
}
else if(searchQuery == "Contact")
{
    window.location = "Contact.html";
}
else if(searchQuery == "Sitemap")
{
    window.location = "Sitemap.html";
}
else
{
    window.location = "noresult.html";
}
}
```

So that way when ever someone goes to search they have a limited amount of options in the pre-populated list and which ever one they select leads them to your target page! I can't take all the credit, but I hope that helps!